# Spark/Java : Not serializable issue - Kryo serialization

Tags: java, apache-spark, serialization, apache-spark-sql, kryo

What I am missing about kryo serialization?

Class1 and Class3 are not java serializable classes (no default constructors, neither getters and setters)

When I try to "use" an instance, that was created out of Spark context, inside Spark, I get a serialization issue, whether I register Classe3 as a Kryo class or not.

**Works fine:**

```
Dataset<Class1> ds = spark.createDataset(classes, Encoders.kryo(Class1.class));

Dataset<String> df = df.map((MapFunction<Class1, String>) class1 -> class1.getName(), Encoders.STRING());

df.show();
```

**Serialization error caused by Class3**

```
spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .master("local[*]")
        .config(new SparkConf().registerKryoClasses(new Class[] {Class3.class}))
        .appName("spark_test")
        .getOrCreate();

Class3 class3 = Class3.getInstance();

Dataset<Class1> ds = spark.createDataset(classes, Encoders.kryo(Class1.class));

Dataset<String> df = df.map((MapFunction<Class1, String>) class1 -> class1.getName() + "-" class3.getId(), Encoders.STRING());

df.show();
```

Comment: can u try passing the value of `class3.getId()` instead of calling this function in map?

Comment: @Amit, I can't. It is just an example to understand why it is not working. In real code I'll  probably need to access many differente attributes from this class3.

Comment: I believe whatever code you have posted is part of a Scala Object or class. And I am thinking that when you try to access class3.getId, spark is trying to serialize the scala object itself as `Class3 class3 = Class3.getInstance();` is member variable of that Scala class or object. Hence I requested you to check what happens when you pass the value of class3.getId.

Comment: @Amit, If I pass the value of class3.getId(), or even if I call Class3.getInstance().getId() inside the function, it works fine. For neither of the cases I need to register Class3 as Kryo class

Comment: Yeah, I believe then the Scala Object that enclose your `Class3 class3 = Class3.getInstance();` , needs to be serializable. Because when you call map with `class3.getId`, the closure that is passed to executor would need to serialize the object where class3 variable belongs to. This could be avoided if you extract the value before hand and pass it.

Comment: Yes, true. I managed to fix it just implementing java.io.Serializable. But, it does not totally answer my question since the Classe3 still not serializable by definition (no default constructor, no setters/getters and its is singleton). Seems that Spark just want to make sure you really want to serialize it. Weird!

Comment: +What the kryo resgistration is about? I could not find an utilization for that so far!

Comment: Kryo will serialize object of Class3. However as I mentioned in my previous comment, when Spark driver send closure to be executed on the executor, it will have to serialize Scala object that has your code itself as you have declared it as a member variable. In general, whatever code you write in a map ( or transformation) , will need to be sent to the executor by serializing it over the network. Hope this helps you. If this explains your doubt, I can write my answer based on this and then you can mark this question answered.

Comment: ok, do it @Amit, I'll accept your answer. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the discussion that happened in the comments to form an answer - 
When you are trying to invoke a transformation, Spark driver will have to create and ship a closure for the code within that transformation to the executor(s) which is responsible for running it. In your case the line of code `Class3 class3 = Class3.getInstance();`, is part of the Scala Object that enclose the creation and usage of Spark context to arrive at some result, a driver application. Hence when you try to pass `class3` in the map transformation, driver is trying to serialize the enclosing Scala object. This scala object is not Serializable by itself unless you implement serializable hence you are getting Serialization issue.

Re:Kryo Serialization - Because you have registered your Class3 with Kryo, it will help you serialize the Class3 instance, however it won't serialize the Composite object which has Class3 instance as a variable.

Hence if you extract the value of `class3.getId()` and then pass it to your map transformation, you do not need Class3 to be registered with Kryo.

In your example enclosing Scala object I mentioned above is same as Driver application.

Hope this helps.